# apache2: start processes with other than www-data user

Tags: apache-2.2, www-data

apache2 seem to start new processes with www-data user. How could I make it start new processes with some other user? ubuntu 11.04 by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can only be changed globally (not for single processes or vhosts) with the statements [`User`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#user) and [`Group`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mpm_common.html#group) in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`. For CGI's, you can use the [`suexec`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/suexec.html) feature to spawn processes with another user id.

Answer (score 2):

Open the `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file and change `User` and `Group` to whatever user, group you want.